# Kivy/Python trying to activate/deactivate buttons on drag in a grid layout

Tags: python, button, kivy, grid-layout, drag

I'm trying to create a style of button that works like a regular button but I also want to be able to trigger multiple buttons with a single click and drag across the row/column of buttons that I am trying to disable.

I have some starter code, the code works exactly as intended when dragging from left to right or from top to bottom, but not from right to left or bottom to top.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


def pointInRect(point, rect):
    x1, y1, w, h = rect
    x2, y2 = x1+w, y1+h
    x, y = point
    if (x >= x1 and x < x2) and (y >= y1 and y < y2):
        return True
    return False

class TouchInput(Widget):
    def __init__(self, cb, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TouchInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cb = cb
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.cb( touch.button, touch.pos )
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.cb( None, touch.pos )

class CustomButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, bg_color=None, **kwargs):
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mouse_button = None
        self.mouse_entered_while_down = False
        
        self.enabled = True

        self.text = name

        self.background_normal = ''
        self.background_down = ''
        self.default_color = (0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 1 )
        self.pressed_color = (.66, .66, .66, 1)
        self.disabled_color = (.125, .125, .125, 1)
        
        toucher = TouchInput( self.on_touch )
        toucher.size = self.size
        toucher.pos = self.pos
        self.add_widget ( toucher )
        
        self.colorize()
        
    def colorize(self, bg_color=None, text_color=None):
        if not bg_color:
            bg_color = self.disabled_color if not self.enabled else self.default_color
        
        text_color = (1 - bg_color[0],  1 - bg_color[1], 1 - bg_color[2], bg_color[3])

        self.background_color = bg_color
        self.color = text_color

    def on_touch(self, button, pos):
        self.mouse_button = button
        
        if pointInRect( pos, self.pos + self.size ):
            if self.mouse_button:
                self.mouse_enter()
            else:
                self.mouse_leave()

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        pos = args[1]
        if self.mouse_button:
            if pointInRect( pos, self.pos + self.size ):
                if not self.mouse_entered_while_down:
                    self.mouse_enter()
            else:
                if self.mouse_entered_while_down:
                    self.mouse_leave()
 
    def mouse_leave(self, *args):
        self.enabled = not self.enabled
        self.colorize()
        self.mouse_entered_while_down = False
 
    def mouse_enter(self, *args):
        self.colorize(bg_color=self.pressed_color)
        self.mouse_entered_while_down = True

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=5, spacing=5, padding=5)
        for i in range(25):
            layout.add_widget( CustomButton(name=str(i)) )
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested; I solved my issue with the following code:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    self.mouse_button = None
    if pointInRect( touch.pos, self.pos + self.size ):
        self.mouse_leave()
        
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    self.mouse_button = touch.button
    if pointInRect( touch.pos, self.pos + self.size ):
        self.mouse_enter()

def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
    pos = args[1]
    if self.mouse_button:
        if pointInRect( pos, self.pos + self.size ):
            if not self.mouse_entered_while_down:
                self.mouse_enter()
        else:
            if self.mouse_entered_while_down:
                self.mouse_leave()
```